# How can I get data of drag- and dropzone?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a running HTML5 Native Drag & Drop - Page with several div-boxes and items. When I drag an item from one box into another box, I want to save the item and the "new" box with ajax in mysql-database. How can I receive the number of the dropzone-box?

Thank you in advance
Dirk

```
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}
function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  ev.dataTransfer.clearData();
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  $.ajax({
      url:"update.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:{pid:data},
      success:function(data)
      {
       alert(data);
      }
    });
}
</script>

<div id="102" class="listx" data-zell="102" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div class="zellbox bgh"><strong>Box: 102</strong></div>
<div id="5" class=" item divider shaft" data-set="5" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><span>First Name | S</span>
</div></div>

<div id="104" class="listx" data-zell="104" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div class="zellbox hfr"><strong>Box: 104</strong></div>
<div id="6" class=" item divider shaft" data-set="6" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
<span>Theo Test | S</span>
</div></div>
```

I expect this in the alert box

    `[pid]=>5 // this value I receive
    [box]=>104`

When I drop a item of box 102

Answer (score 0):

```
Solved by mysql

function drop(ev, target) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  //    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  //    console.log(target.id + " : " + ev.target.id) 
  //    console.log(ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/html")); 
  //   console.log(ev.dataTransfer.getData("text")); 
      var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
      var tx= target.id;
  data=data+'#'+tx;
  $.ajax({
      url:"update.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:{pid:data},
      success:function(data)
      {
       window.location.reload(false);
      }
    });
}

<div id="list-200#x" class="listx " data-max="4" data-zell="200" ondrop="drop(event,this)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
```